# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Package doesnt load correctly

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, nuget-package

I am trying to open a project that I have been working on for a while now. Everything was going well. and then I had to download FileZilla for ftp works. That instance somehow switched my default browser from MS Edge to Opera which was downloaded with FileZilla. So when I ran my VS2010 project it initially ran on Opera. I deleted the Opera and tried to use Edge like before.But my solution folder doesn't seem to load and neither does my project run without crashing .
I have tried to uninstall and re-install when I do that I get these errors

[PACKAGE DID NOT LOAD CORRECTLY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6lNc.jpg)

[PACAGE DID NOT LOAD CORRECTLY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVJFG.png)

[SAME AS PREVIOUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfpQH.jpg)

[SAME AS PREVIOUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu1CP.jpg)

[similarly. My solution folder doesn't load anything which contains all the packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4loCU.png)

[When I  FORCE  run my project it runs and then the IDE doesn't respond for a while and then it says "Unable to start the program (file path) There are no more files"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW7gS.png)